# Instagram API: 'User' object has no attribute 'counts'

Tags: python, python-2.7, instagram, python-2.x, instagram-api

I'm using Python's `python-instagram` library to access `users/user-id` endpoint of Instagram API:

According to the documentation, this is the ideal response that the above endpoint generates:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to find the data associated with the `counts` attribute from the generated response:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = <my_access_token>

api = InstagramAPI(client_secret='xxxxxxxx', access_token = access_token[0])
usr = api.user_search('XXXXX')

print usr[0].counts
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'counts'
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user_search method return a list of user with limited information:
**'bio', 'full_name', 'id', 'profile_picture', 'username', 'website'**

You must access each user of the list with is id and then you can use the **counts** attribute :
`first_user = api.user(usr[0].id)` then `first_user.counts`.

Comment: Printing usr[0]['counts'] raised an error. This is what dir(usr[0]) returned: `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'bio', 'full_name', 'id', 'object_from_dictionary', 'profile_picture', 'username', 'website']`. Printing usr[0] returned this: `User: XXXX`

Comment: Ok, it seems the search return a list of user with the following information : **'bio', 'full_name', 'id', 'profile_picture', 'username', 'website'**. So you can't use the **counts** attribute. You must get the use's infomation with his id : **ex_user = api.user(usr[0].id)** then **ex_user.counts**